# VB.NET 2003 copy log4net.config to bin folder

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, .net-1.1, visual-studio-2003

I'm using VS.NET 2003 and VB.NET. I have placed my log4net.config file in the same folder as the source code and I want to automatically copy the log4net.config file to the bin folder just as the app.config file is copied to bin. Is there an automatic way to do this?

Comment: "I'm using VS.NET 2003 and VB.NET." - I'm so very sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Include it as a resource, and choose copy always.

You can do this by:

1. Click on your vbproj file and choose "Add Existing item"
2. Navigte to the config file and select it
3. Right click on the config file and make sure it is not set to "embedded resource" (you dont want it embedded in your exe or dll)
4. Make sure its build action is set to "Copy always"
5. Build, and check your build directory it should be there

I dont have my IDE open, so the steps might need a little tweaking.

Comment: I don't see this option in the VS.NET 2003 IDE.

Comment: The build action has only 4 selections i.e. None,compile,content and Embedded Resource. I don't see the "Copy Always" option that you have suggested.

Comment: Thanks for your time GrayWizardx. Unfortunately selecting "Content" still doesn't copy the Log4net.config to the bin folder.

Comment: Just to clarify for anyone reading: the "Copy always" option is a separate project property that was introduced in VS2005; it doesn't exist in VS2003.

Answer (score 0):

Add a post build event - [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20200929004600/http://geekswithblogs.net/dchestnutt/archive/2006/05/30/80113.aspx)

Something like:-

copy "$(ProjectDir)log4net.config" "$(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)"

should do it.

Comment: Unfortunately, VS2003 doesn't support build events, so this won't work.